# Laravel Object interation

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-blade

These are my tables. A many to many relationship between a user and a club.

```
User Table 
Club Table
ClubUser Table with User_id and Club_id
```

Im looping over each club and i want to check if the user has requested to join the club or not. If they have applied then a "withdraw" button will appear else a "Apply" button will appear.

**The problem is** when i get all clubs, it also gets all associated users. So i got multiple buttons when looping. How do I do i limit it to the user logged in, so it only displays what he have clicked.

My controller

```
    public function index()
{
    $clubs = club::with('user')->get();
    return view('clubs/index', compact('clubs'));
}
```

My view

```
       @foreach($clubs as $club)

            <div class="club-apply">

                @forelse($club->user as $user)
                   <!-- Withdraw button here -->
                    @if($user->pivot->user_id == Auth::user()->id)
                        <form method="POST" action="{{route('clubs.withdraw', $club->id )}}">
                            @method('delete')
                            @csrf
                            <input type="hidden" name="club_id" value="{{$club->id}}">
                            <button type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-secondary">Withdraw</button>
                        </form>
                    @else

                    @endif

                    @empty
                         <!-- Apply button here -->
                        <form method="POST" action="{{route('clubs.apply', Auth::user()->id)}}">
                            @method('put')
                            @csrf
                            <input type="hidden" name="club_id" value="{{$club->id}}">
                            <button type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-primary">Apply</button>
                        </form>

                @endforelse

       @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you are grabbing all clubs when I think you just want to grab the logged in user and get all their clubs? If so you can do something like

`$clubs = Auth:user()->clubs`

`return view('clubs/index', compact('clubs'));`

You can achieve this because you have a many to many relationship.

Comment: There for you wouldn&#39;t need to filter through clubs in your view. By removing the @forelse

Answer (score 0):

you can add an additional clause when getting all the clubs. This can be done with something like:

```
$userId = 'something';

$clubs = club::whereHas('user', function($query)
{
    $query->where('user_id', $userId);

})->get();
```